# Xcode 12. How to change autocompletion view color?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

[image]
Here is the new Xcode 12 view of autocompletion window. The question is how to change colors of background, size and color of text. Maybe other colors of that view.

Answer (score 0):

### Can't be modified alone, only indirectly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What option to change?

Comment: only change Theme